# YCM for vim including headers and autocompleting?

Tags: vim, autocomplete, include, youcompleteme

Pardon my ignorance, would like to inquire regarding another question. I recently installed YCM for vim and im abit confused what is it supposed to do.

I expected when i do a 
 `#include <s`   it would suggest stdlib/stdio and other library headers however it is not happening. when i have a struct in another .h file and I include it into a .c file, it does not recognize the struct until i type it once. Eg :

In crate.h

```
typedef struct 
{
    int weight; 
    int capacity;
}crate;
```

in main.c

```
#include "crate.h" 

crate temp = {1,2};
```

After i typed out crate once then it would auto complete for the following few crates structs that i create. Is this supposed to be how it's like?

Comment: Did you Compile YCM with semantic support for C-family languages:

    cd ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe
    ./install.py --clang-completer

Comment: @byaruhaf i believe i ./install.py --all though ? is the clang completer not in ?

Comment: Run the install again, and look at the output from configure to ensure that it's enabling semantic support. You might be missing some of the required tools or libraries.